# GCC cross-compiling using a rootfs

Tags: c, linux, gcc, nvidia-jetson

We are currently developing an application for an ARM embedded system that is running a full Linux OS (NVIDIA Jetson TX2). I have a copy of the rootfs from the embedded system as well as the GNU toolchain for ARM version 8.2-2018.08.
I am having difficulty getting the GCC compiler (`gcc-arm-8.2-2018.11-x86_64-aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc`) to look in the correct directory of the rootfs for both include and library files.

I have set the —sysroot variable to point to the location of my sysroot. However, looking in the lib and include directories there is a subfolder that `usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu` that contains further include and libraries and it is these ones that are actually the ones needed. For example instead of the libraries being located in `$rootfs/usr/lib` or `$rootfs/usr/local/lib`, instead, the libraries are in `$rootfs/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu` I have tested and using the -I/-L commands I can get the project o compile.

My questions are as follows

- Is using the -I and -L the "correct" way to be doing this? If not, what is?
- Why does linux place these libraries in this other directory?
- When compiling using --sysroot I can see that other non-sysroot directories are being checked. Why would gcc be doing this?

Comment: Use only sysroot=dir, don't worry about `/usr/lib/aarch64...`. gcc reads crt0.o and similar things from that dir, such files are not existent in your rootfs, unless you also installed the compiler inside the rootfs. `Why would gcc be doing this?` What options are you using? It's hard to guess why without knowing what it does. If you have the roofs up and maintanable, and the architecture is something popular like aarch64, you can install qemu-static and binfmt and just chroot into the rootfs.

Comment: Sorry,  was slightly unclear; there are no libraries in $rootfs/usr/lib or $rootfs/us/local/lib. All the libarry files appears to be in $rootfs/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu.This is just a copy of the embedded system's default image, is it possible that the compiler that was installed on it at default was installed to there?

Comment: Then why do you want to use `--sysroot` options to gcc at all? If none of the standard libraries are on your sysroot, what is the use case for this option?

Comment: I am assuming that these libraries are correctly compiled and working for the kernel/architecture that is on the embedded device? Is that not the way to do it?

Comment: Which libraries? If there are no libraries in $rootfs/usr/lib then why would you want to use it? Just stick to what your compiler provides. Unless you want to use some external libraries available only on your $rootfs - then using `-I` and `-L` would be correct, because there is (may?) be no standard library implementation on your $rootfs.

Comment: Standard libraries (glibc etc.). There are libraries under the aarch64 directory that are the standard libraries I just can’t figure out why they would be there rather than up a directory. I am statically cross compiling compiling from x86 to arm64 and so would have thought I’d need to use the libraries for the actual architecture

Comment: You should forget about sysroot and simply link rootfs/(usr/)lib/aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc to /(usr/)lib/aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc. The /lib/<arch-tripplet>/ path is the multiarch path from Debian based systems (analog to /usr/include/<arch-triplet>/ gcc has always used) allowing for libraries from multiple architectures, personalities and libcs to coexist on a system.